# How to use eureka+feign without spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka

I have a `eureka` server and some services(`spring-boot` apps), they register to the `eureka` and use the `Feign` to communicate with each other. I also have a big old app using `spring`. it is packed into `war` and deployed into a `jetty server`. I can't rewrite it using `spring-boot`, but the app has to communicate with other services through the `Feign` and `Eureka`. Also i can use `spring-cloud` into the app if it helps.

How could i use eureka+feign without spring-boot? Please help me.

Comment: I'm looking at doing the same thing. Have you had any luck creating a Ribbon client without spring boot?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409492/eureka-service-discovery-without-spring-boot/46011852#46011852

Answer (score 0):

The spring-boot is intended to add extra jars on the classpath of your application and nothing else, with this idea in mind, I think so, you could use eureka and Feign with no problems, you should only check which jars are being wrapped inside spring-boot applications, and add them to your existing spring app, in order to get eureka and feign up and running

Answer (score -1):

**Scenario 1： Spring boot application as API consumer.**

In this scenario, the most simple way is just add some configuration like this:

```
say-hello:
  ribbon:
   eureka:
    enabled: false
  listOfServers: localhost:8090,localhost:9092,localhost:9999
  ServerListRefreshInterval: 15000
```

after this you can use FeignClient communicate with the old app.

more details please see: https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/

**Scenario 2: The old application as API consumer**

Please ref:
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations

Eureka already provide rest operations, that you can query service instances info.