# Eureka service discovery without Spring-boot using spring 4 instead of spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4, netflix-eureka

Refering to this question [Eureka service discovery without Spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409492).

I want to implement Eureka Server using spring 4 without using spring boot.

Is their amy way to do this. If possible please share a working sample.

Comment: Spring Boot is using Spring 4 so what is the difference? Why not simply use Spring Boot to make your life easier. If you really want to not use spring boot take a look at the auto configuration of those projects and do that manually.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35409492/1686330