# Spring 4 application register as client to Eureka

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netflix-eureka, spring-4

I have a **Spring 4** application (not Spring Boot) and I want it to register to Eureka service discovery.

**Is there any way to do it?** because all tutorials are tightly connected to Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done:

In the "webapp" module, I have created a class which implements InitalizingBean, and override the methods. In post construct method, I have just send POST request to Eureka, and register my application as a service.

My application is now registered as microservice in Eureka

Comment: Hi, i am facing the same requirement as you did, can you please elabrote your solution? For example, what did you send when you POST the request to Eureka?

Answer (score 1):

This question have been asked here before, basically you need to do something like this,

```
 DiscoveryManager.getInstance().initComponent(new MyDataCenterInstanceConfig(), new DefaultEurekaClientConfig());

  String vipAddress = "MY-SERVICE";

    InstanceInfo nextServerInfo = null;
    try {
        nextServerInfo = DiscoveryManager.getInstance()
                .getEurekaClient()
                .getNextServerFromEureka(vipAddress, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot get an instance of example service to talk to from eureka");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("Found an instance of example service to talk to from eureka: "
            + nextServerInfo.getVIPAddress() + ":" + nextServerInfo.getPort());

    System.out.println("healthCheckUrl: " + nextServerInfo.getHealthCheckUrl());
    System.out.println("override: " + nextServerInfo.getOverriddenStatus());

    System.out.println("Server Host Name "+ nextServerInfo.getHostName() + " at port " + nextServerInfo.getPort() );
```

You will have to add a configuration file to the class path. Eureka client uses this file to read the information about the eureka servers.

```
eureka.preferSameZone=true
eureka.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.decoderName=JacksonJson
```

Down below are the Maven dependencies that you need. Eureka1 supports JDK7 though some part of it has been built with JDK8. However I had to provide older versions of "archaius-core" and "servo-core" to make it run with JDK7

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.archaius</groupId>
        <artifactId>archaius-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.servo</groupId>
        <artifactId>servo-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here are links to Netflix own Eureka documentation and also a link to the original Stack Overflow thread discussing this topic
Eureka: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki
Original thread: [Eureka service discovery without Spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409492/eureka-service-discovery-without-spring-boot)

Comment: I saw that answer, but it's not very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same difficulty of registering services with spring mvc 4 with eureka but using the SIDECAR of spring I could solve it and be able to add the other components such as Ribbon, so you must create a spring-boot project to add the dependency of sidecar, then to the spring mvc project when deploying modify the port so that it leaves like this (example: localhost: 9090 / service1) also you must have a service that is "health" with this name that returns "status: UP" (localhost: 9090 / health), I found all this configuration in this project of which I was guided (https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-cloud-sidecar-sample)
Also the sidecar is independent of the language of the service only needs the service "Health" to be able to register it in eureka.Therefore you have a sidecar which listens to the project with spring mvc, the eureka escuha to the sidecar.In the repository of which I There is a complete description of how the components interact.